# sshfs connection reset by peer with Synology NAS

Tags: ssh, nas

I recently bought a synology NAS (DS216i).

I enabled ssh on it and setup some share. I can successfully ssh into the box but not mount with sshfs.

```
sshfs user@ip:/volume1 nas
```

gives me the following error:

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I've long given up samba and rely on sshfs for sharing stuff. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

For `sshfs` you need a `sftp` subsystem enabled, that might not be there by default. First of all, verify that you can connect with command-line `sftp`. Most probably it will fail the same way so you will have to install a `sftp-server` to the NAS.

Answer (score 2):

On a DS218j I've had a similar problem. Enabling SSH is not enough.

I'll guess the names for specific options, because my UI is not in English.

There is a "Control Panel" application and in "File Services" > "FTP" scroll down do "SFTP" section, and check the "Enable SFTP service" checkbox, port number: 22.

Now, `scp` and `sftp` work fine, and file dates and times are set correclty (unlike when using Samba mounts).

One thing I'm still trying to resolve is mounting it with `sshfs` - it works for a while and then hangs (maybe after some inactivity period). Bigger transfers with `scp` seem to work fine, but a mounted subdirectory suddenly becomes empty, e.g. when opening in a file browser.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior on the DS218+

Comment: Update: after these few years, something must have gotten better, because I've been using `sshfs` without problems recently. Still, I usually mount, do transfers and unmount, not keeping it mounted for too long. But, many small or large files, reading or writing -- seem not to fail now.